# C# and MySql Procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, procedure

I have 2 tables. Main_items and Help_items.

Main_items has these columns
(main_items_id,main_items_name)

Help_items has these columns
(help_items_id,Help_items_name, main_items_id).

I wrote this Procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `thamer1`(in main_items_id_ int, 
out res int)
BEGIN
declare a int;
declare b int;

select count(help_items_id)
into a from help_items
where main_items_id=main_items_id_;

if a=0 then
    set b=(main_items_id_*10)+1;
    set res=b;
else
    select COALESCE(max(help_items_id),0)+1
    into res
    from help_items
    where main_items_id=main_items_id_;
end if;
END
```

This procedure works with MySql WrokBench.

And this for c# code

```
private void a_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection mysqlcon6 = new 
MySqlConnection(connectString))
        {
            mysqlcon6.Open();
            MySqlCommand mysqlcmd6 = new MySqlCommand("thamer1", mysqlcon6);

            mysqlcmd6.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            mysqlcmd6.CommandText = "thamer1";
            mysqlcmd6.Parameters.Add("@main_items_id_", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = a.Text;
            mysqlcmd6.Parameters.Add("@res", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value=HITEM.Text;
            mysqlcmd6.ExecuteNonQuery();
           // MessageBox.Show("saved");
            // GridFill();
        }
    }
```

I select value (for main_items_id) from DataGrideView and fetch it into textbox named `a`.

When I press ENTER I get this Message

> System.FormatException:' Input string was not in a correct format'

I hope to help me to solve this error.

Comment: Please debug your code and step through it line by line so you can identify exactly what line the error is occurring on.  Then provide the line causing the error and let us know the details then we can help.

Comment: A stack trace would help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the portion of this line that sets the parameter value:

```
mysqlcmd6.Parameters.Add("@res", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value=HITEM.Text;
```

It looks like you expect that to bind the result of `@res` to the `HITEM` textbox, and that's not what happens. `HITEM.Text` is just a string, and when you assign that value to an int parameter, you're telling MySql you expect it to be able to parse that string into an int.

Instead, only create the parameter, like this:

```
mysqlcmd6.Parameters.Add("@res", MySqlDbType.Int32);
```

You also need to tell ADO.Net this is an OUTPUT parameter. Then check the parameter value *after* the query runs by assigning the parameter value **to** HITEM.Text rather than from HITEM.Text:

```
private void a_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //You can re-use the *names* of these variables, since their scopes are limited to the method
    //You can also stack them to share the same scope block and reduce nesting/indentation
    using (var con = new MySqlConnection(connectString))
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("thamer1", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //  mysqlcmd6.CommandText = "thamer1"; //you already did this in constructor. Don't need to do it again
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@main_items_id_", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = a.Text;
        //DON'T assign to the Value, but DO make sure ADO.Net understands this is an OUTPUT parameter
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@res", MySqlDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        //wait as long as possible to call Open()
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //Now you can assign **to** HITEM.Text, rather than from it.
        HITEM.Text = cmd.Parameters["@res"].Value;
    }
    //End the scope as soon as possible, so the connection can be disposed faster
    // MessageBox.Show("saved");
    // GridFill();
}
```

And here it is again without all the extra comments:

```
private void a_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    using (var con = new MySqlConnection(connectString))
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("thamer1", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@main_items_id_", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = a.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@res", MySqlDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        HITEM.Text = cmd.Parameters["@res"].Value;
    }
}
```

Even better practice would move all your SQL methods to a separate class, away from your event handlers. The event handlers should only need to call methods in the new class, like this:

```
public static class DB
{
    private static string connectionString = "...";

    public static int thamer(int main_item_id)
    {
        using (var con = new MySqlConnection(connectString))
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("thamer1", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@main_items_id_", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = main_item_id;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@res", MySqlDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return (int)cmd.Parameters["@res"].Value;
        }
    }
}

private void a_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    HITEM.Text = DB.thamer(int.Parse(a.Text)).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 mysqlcmd6.Parameters.Add("@main_items_id_", 
MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = a.Text;
            mysqlcmd6.Parameters.Add("@res", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 
HITEM.Text;
```

to

```
int value1 = 0;
int value2 = 0;

if (!Int32.Text.TryParse(a.Text) || !Int32.TryParse(HITEM.Text))
{
    return;
}
 mysqlcmd6.Parameters.Add("@main_items_id_",  MySqlDbType.Int32).Value =  value1;
 mysqlcmd6.Parameters.Add("@res", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = value2;
```

Comment: If the values aren't valid integers, this is still going to throw an exception.

Comment: `MySqlDbType.Int32` datatype is integers, so he should validate the value

Comment: answer is updated, so I used `int.TryParse` instead, it will not throw exception

Comment: This won't compile. TryParse returns a `bool` and puts the value into the passed `out` parameter.

Comment: @stuard I agree, but I think there must be initial validation, so I just updated the answer to convert string to integer value.

Comment: If there _was_ validation, then there wouldn't be a question (assuming this is the cause).

Comment: You're all barking up the wrong tree. Parsing the bad string may cause the exception, but `res` is an `out` parameter. He shouldn't assign anything to it in the first place, nor care at all about the current value of `HITEM.Text`, since he intends to replace it. Instead he needs to assign the value _from_ the res parameter after the query runs.

Comment: `"@res"` expects  integer, so `Text` value needs to be validated and checked before adding it as `parameters` into `MySqlCommand`

Comment: @Saif That's only true if res is an input parameter. That's not what the OP wants.